# Is there an open subset $A$ of $[0,1]^2$ with measure $>\frac{1}{100}$ that satisfies this property?

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, geometric-measure-theory

Can we find for any given $\varepsilon>0$ an open subset $A\subseteq[0,1]^2$ with measure $>\frac{1}{100}$ such that, for any smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ of length $1$, the set $\gamma+A=\{\gamma(t)+a;t\in[0,1],a\in A\}$ does not contain any balls of radius $\varepsilon$?

I wouldn't mind changing the $\frac{1}{100}$ for any other positive constant. Also, I ask about smooth curves but it may make more sense to consider in general $1$-Lipschitz functions $\gamma:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$.

For context, a positive answer to this question could be useful for [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420897/what-is-the-smallest-size-of-a-shape-in-which-all-fixed-n-polyominos-can-fit/421175#421175). But the question is also interesting in itself, of course.

Comment: If $A$ is open, it contains an open ball of radius $x$, now if we take $\gamma(t) = \sin\frac{20 \pi t}{x}$, $\gamma +A$ fills unit square  (as moving even just this ball along $\gamma$ fills it). I guess something is wrong with this reasoning, but I can't find what.

Comment: @mihaild I don't understand very well, your curve $\gamma$ is $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, not $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, and I don't think it has length $1$

Comment: Thanks, that's what I missed: the restriction on length.

Comment: Btw, I am not sure why the "multivariable calculus" tag is more appropiate than the "recreational mathematics" one on this question. This is not part of any mathematics curriculum that I know of

Comment: Would you be interested in the case when $\gamma$ has length, say, 10?

Comment: The case of $\gamma$ having length $10$ would imply the question as above, because any smooth curve of length $1$ is a subset of a smooth curve of length $10$. But any ideas of how to solve problems similar to the one above are welcome. For example I would also be interested in the case of the curves $\gamma$ having length $\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Oh and if you mean that if the curves $\gamma$ have length $10$ the answer is negative then yes, I am interested (for some reason I think that the answer of these problems is going to be positive but it's a baseless belief)

Comment: Yes, I was asking having in mind the negative answer (baseless belief as well!)

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422493/is-there-an-open-subset-a-of-0-12-with-measure-frac1100-that-sati